# Query to reorganize dates

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I need to do a transformation of a Postgres database table and I don't know where to start.
This is the table:

```
| Customer   Code | Activity | Start Date |
|:---------------:|:--------:|:----------:|
|       100       |     A    | 01/05/2017 |
|       100       |     A    | 19/07/2017 |
|       100       |     B    | 18/09/2017 |
|       100       |     C    | 07/12/2017 |
|       101       |     A    | 11/02/2018 |
|       101       |     B    | 02/04/2018 |
|       101       |     B    | 14/06/2018 |
|       100       |     A    | 13/07/2018 |
|       100       |     B    | 14/08/2018 |
```

Customers can perform activities A, B and C, always in that order.
To carry out activity B he/she has to carry out activity A. To carry out C, he/she has to carry out activity A, then to B.
An activity or cycle can be performed more than once by the same customer.

I need to reorganize the table in this way, placing the beginning and end of each step:

```
| Customer   Code | Activity | Start Date |  End Date  |
|:---------------:|:--------:|:----------:|:----------:|
|       100       |     A    | 01/05/2017 | 18/09/2017 |
|       100       |     B    | 18/09/2017 | 07/12/2017 |
|       100       |     C    | 07/12/2017 | 13/07/2018 |
|       101       |     A    | 11/02/2018 | 02/04/2018 |
|       101       |     B    | 02/04/2018 |            |
|       100       |     A    | 13/07/2018 | 14/08/2018 |
|       100       |     B    | 14/08/2018 |            |
```

Comment: what is the data type of `Start date`?

Answer (score 3):

Here is approach at this gaps-and-islands problem:

```
select
    customer_code,
    activity,
    start_date,
    case when (activity, lead(activity) over(partition by customer_code order by start_date))
        in (('A', 'B'), ('B', 'C'), ('C', 'A'))
        then lead(start_date) over(partition by customer_code order by start_date)
    end end_date
    from (
        select 
            t.*, 
            lead(activity) over(partition by customer_code order by start_date) lead_activity
        from mytable t
    ) t
where activity is distinct from lead_activity
```

The query starts by removing consecutive rows that have the same `customer_code` and `activity`. Then, we use conditional logic to bring in the `start_date` of the next row when the `activty` is in sequence.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c780559e831cd5b24c3dbb83af3f7514)**:

```
customer_code | activity | start_date | end_date  
------------: | :------- | :--------- | :---------
          100 | A        | 2017-07-19 | 2017-09-18
          100 | B        | 2017-09-18 | 2017-12-07
          100 | C        | 2017-12-07 | 2018-07-13
          100 | A        | 2018-07-13 | 2018-08-14
          100 | B        | 2018-08-14 | null      
          101 | A        | 2018-02-11 | 2018-06-14
          101 | B        | 2018-06-14 | null
```